# Import a JavaScript module inside a namespace, e.g., for D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am using D3. In a JavaScript file I could write

```
import * as d3 from "d3"
```

and then I could do something like

```
d3.select("body")
```

That's not desirable, because then I get all of D3 and I just want what I need.

I could also write

```
import { select } from "d3-selection"
```

and then I can write

```
select("body")
```

That's not great either because now I am writing different code than before.

Is there anyway to import just the bindings I want, e.g.

```
import { csv } from "d3-fetch"
import { select } from "d3-selection"
```

but still write `d3.select("body")` or `d3.csv("myfile.csv")` and the like within the D3 namespace?

Comment: When you say "get all of D3," do you mean "only transfer over the Internet to my browser page the code from D3 that I'm actually going to execute?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, that's a more precise way of putting it. I want to refer to D3 as if I had the whole thing, but I don't want to send the whole thing to the browser. For instance, in the example above using Parcel, the difference is about 28 KB vs 462 KB.

Comment: You could do something like `import { select } from "d3-selection"; const d3 = { select };`

Comment: If this is possible, it would be because "tree shaking" is used.  See https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/